# Create CI on VSTS with multiple git submodules from different project repositories

Tags: git, azure-devops, desktop-application, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am building CI on VSTS for one Desktop application,

In the build .sln need some git submodules from other project git repo.

Please suggest the way out to achieve the same.

Build solution URL: `https://xxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_git/test1`

Submodule URL: `https://xxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_git/test2`

Comment: So have you already added test2 as submodule for test1? And do you want to build the project(s) in submodule repo (test2), and then build projects in the main repo (test1)? What's the detail build logs did you meet?

Comment: Please find below error massage receiving  Shared\Test2\Libraries\Data\Test2.data.csproj(190,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\DMSLLC\Utils\MSBuild\Test2.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk. Shared\Test2\Libraries\Diagnostics\ErrorHandling\ErrorHandler.cs(17,30): Error CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'ErrorHandler.mDefaultLocation'

Comment: VS Build task does not build solutions/projects in submodule. So if project in the main repo test1 referred build output from the submodule repo test2, you need to **add an additional VS Build task to specify the solution(s) in test2 repo** (`test2/**/*.sln`)  firstly before building the solutions (`**/*.sln`)from test repo.

Comment: Hi Marina, Thanks for the reply,
Please tell me how to add multiple sources to build different repository solution
as the 2nd repo is under different Team project

Comment: The common way is treat test2 as submodule for test1 repo, and then build solutions from test2 repo by specifying the relative path. If you still has problems, please share the .gitsubmodule file and the build definition and build logs in one drive.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Checkout submodules" in the Get Sources step of the build[image].

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say that the code in test1 needs the code in test2 in order to be released.  So you clone repo1 by going to the command line and typing:

```
git clone https://{projectname}.visualstudio.com/_git/test1
```

Great.  That brings down the code for test1.

Next, create a submodule reference from Repo1 to test2.

```
git submodule add https://{projectname}.visualstudio.com/_git/test2
```

You’ve now got the code from test2 in a folder off the root of test1.  You also get a new file named ‘.gitmodules’.  That `.gitmodules` file contains the mapping from test1 to test2 and this file should be added, committed, and pushed to test1 along with any other changes that you make.

At this point, you’ve got the local workstation stuff working with submodules.  Next, let’s work on the automated build.

To make this work with TFS Build vNext, it’s really just a matter of a single checkbox.  In a web browser, go to the build definition and click ‘Edit’ to bring up the build editor.  Click on the **Repository** tab to view the git repo settings for this build definition.  Towards the bottom of the list, you’ll see a checkbox option that says “Checkout submodules”.  Check that and hit save.

[image]

That’s it.  When your build runs, the Git checkout step will follow the submodules that you defined in the .gitmodules file and put all that code on disk.  After that, you can do whatever you need to do with that code from the second repository.

Comment: I have already checked the same, still getting below error.

Shared\Test2\Libraries\Data\Test2.data.csproj(190,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\DMSLLC\Utils\MSBuild\Test2.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Shared\Test2\Libraries\Diagnostics\ErrorHandling\ErrorHandler.cs(17,30): Error CS1591: Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member 'ErrorHandler.mDefaultLocation'

Comment: Yes, locally from VS I am able to build the manually, but getting this error only when creating CI on VSTS to automate the process.

Comment: Can you check on the agent which repositories downloaded?

Comment: Using Hosted2017 Agent on VSTS, so not able to check the same.